# Como se faz um botão de login que abre uma nova janela?

Tags: python

Eu estava tentando fazer um programa, com um sistema de login, mas não consegui fazer com que o botão de confirmar acessasse a minha 2° janela(no caso precisaria que o login estivesse certo para que isto ocorresse).

Desde já agradeço.
[image: Este foi o código que eu conseguir criar]

Answer (score 0):

Falta o comando no botão na linha 27.

```
bt = Button(jnl, text="Confirmar", command=janela_do_hub)
```

Comment: Bom dia,

No caso queria que a janela funcionasse apenas se o login estivesse correto, colocando o botão na linha 27 o botão de "confirmar" concede o login independente se o usuário e senha estiverem corretos. Queria poder fazer também que quando o login ou senha estivessem errados aparecesse "Usuário ou senha incorretos!".

Já agradeço pela ajuda!